# What to put in the scheduling tag wiki, since the tag is ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, ambiguous-tags

I am noticing the [scheduling](/questions/tagged/scheduling) tag wiki has answers for different types of scheduling:

- Scheduled tasks (ala cron)
- Thread scheduling
- Activity scheduling (ala Gantt Charts)

If a tag wiki were to be made for it, what should it contain?  Would it be legitimate for a tag to apply to multiple discrete things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those can be retagged with existing variants of "schedule".
For example, for "Scheduled tasks" we already have: [job-scheduling](/questions/tagged/job-scheduling), [scheduled-tasks](/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks), [task-scheduler](/questions/tagged/task-scheduler), [task-scheduling](/questions/tagged/task-scheduling), and [windows-scheduler](/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler) !

Ideally, everything could be retagged with more specific tags -- either existing or newly created -- then [scheduling](/questions/tagged/scheduling) could be banned or aliased into the most popular variant.

**Otherwise**, the wiki might be set to something like...

> This tag is a catchall for questions where "Scheduling" is an
>   important aspect, but that don't quite fit into the existing tags:
>
> [dbms-scheduler](/questions/tagged/dbms-scheduler) [evidence-based-scheduling](/questions/tagged/evidence-based-scheduling)
>   [ischedulingservice](/questions/tagged/ischedulingservice) [job-scheduling](/questions/tagged/job-scheduling) [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler)
>   [radschedular](/questions/tagged/radschedular) [radscheduler](/questions/tagged/radscheduler) [radscheduleview](/questions/tagged/radscheduleview)
>   [resource-scheduling](/questions/tagged/resource-scheduling) [rufus-scheduler](/questions/tagged/rufus-scheduler) [schedule](/questions/tagged/schedule)
>   [scheduled-tasks](/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks) [scheduler](/questions/tagged/scheduler) [scheduling](/questions/tagged/scheduling)
>   [task-scheduler](/questions/tagged/task-scheduler) [task-scheduling](/questions/tagged/task-scheduling) [telerik-scheduler](/questions/tagged/telerik-scheduler)
>   [windows-scheduler](/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler)